# Remove upload button on item Bootstrap Fileinput

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I cannot remove the upload icon from the item box. I'd like to upload all images when I click on the "send" button.
Thank you

[image]

```
var btns = '<input type="hidden" id= "<?= $csrf['name'] ?>" name="<?= $csrf['name'] ?>" value="<?= $csrf['hash'] ?>">';
    $("#images").fileinput({
        uploadExtraData: {<?= $csrf['name'] ?>: "<?= $csrf['hash'] ?>", id_specie: "<?= $specie[0]['id_specie'] ?>"},
        deleteExtraData: {<?= $csrf['name'] ?>: "<?= $csrf['hash'] ?>", id_specie: "<?= $specie[0]['id_specie'] ?>"},
        initialPreview: <?= $immagini ?>,
        initialPreviewConfig: <?= $galleria_immagini ?>,
        initialPreviewAsData: true,
        showCaption: true,
        showUpload: false,
        showRemove: false,
        previewFileType: "image",
        removeLabel: "Elimina",
        uploadLabel: "Carica",
        overwriteInitial: false,
        maxFileSize: 10240,
        uploadUrl: '<?= base_url() ?>specie/do_upload',
        initialCaption: "Carica le immagini",
        uploadAsync: true,
        maxFileCount: 10,
        allowedFileExtensions: ['png', 'jpg' ]
    });



      $("#send").click(function () {
//            $("#images").fileinput({'uploadUrl': '<?= base_url() ?>specie/do_upload'});

    $("#images").fileinput("upload");

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I added this

```
.kv-file-upload{
    color:#fff !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

in `backend\assets\css\colors.css`

Answer (score 1):

```
language: 'en',
showCaption: true,
showPreview: true,
showRemove: true,
showUpload: false, // <------ just set this from true to false
showCancel: true,
showUploadedThumbs: true
```

If this not work than try :-

You can do it in a simple way also simply write in an attribute `data-show-upload="false"` and it I'll work too!!

Comment: @MassimilianoAllegretti bro will you please explain me how?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $("#images").fileinput({
            fileActionSettings: {
                showUpload: false,
            });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

use better:

```
fileActionSettings: {
    showRemove: true,
    showUpload: false, //This remove the upload button
    showZoom: true,
    showDrag: false
},
```

Comment: Why **better** ?